# While loop "continue" not working inside try, except, finally

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, try-except, continue

Trying to run a `while` loop until the input is valid:

```
while True:
    try:
        print('open')    
        num = int(input("Enter number:"))
        print(num)

    except ValueError:
        print('Error:"Please enter number only"') 
        continue #this continue is not working, the loop runs and break at finally

    finally:
        print('close')
        break
```

Need to continue the loop if anything except numbers is entered, but the loop reaches `finally` and `break`s.

Comment: As far as I understand Final, it will be called always after the try block. 
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#defining-clean-up-actions

Comment: @Leo Thanks. Your reference is very useful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`finally` will **always** run after the try-except. You want `else`, which will run **only if the try-block doesn't raise an exception**.

By the way, minimize the code in a try-block, to avoid false-positives.

```
while True:
    inp = input("Enter number: ")
    try:
        num = int(inp)
    except ValueError:
        print('Error: Please enter number only')
        continue
    else:
        print(num)
        break
    print('This will never print')  # Added just for demo
```

Test run:

```
Enter number: f
Error: Please enter number only
Enter number: 15
15
```

Note that the `continue` is not actually needed in your example, so I added a demo `print()` at the bottom of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to remove the `finally:` statement to achieve what you want.

```
while True:
    try:
        print('open')    
        num = int(input("Enter number:"))
        print(num)
        break # stop the loop when int() returns a value

    except ValueError:
        print('Error:"Please enter number only"') 
        continue
```

whatever you need to do after you validate the int() should be outside the `try/except/finally` structure

Comment: you forgot the ```break``` at the end of the ```try```. Else the loop will run infinitely.

Comment: But I need finally to close something

Comment: ```finally``` will always execute either after the ```try``` or after the ```except``` (the only case it will not execute is if you break the loop). Just move the ```break``` to the line after you got the number. (so in this case after ```num = int(input("Enter number:"))````)

Comment: That's why you break the loop inside try: as noticed by @sputnick567!

Comment: @sputnick567 Understood Thanks

Comment: You've got stuff in the try-block that's not being tested, which is not ideal. Use `else` instead. See [my answer](/a/68330712/4518341).